# HTML5 Canvas - How to move an object in a direction?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an object I want to make orbit a star. I've managed to make the object move towards the star, but now I need to set up lateral movement as well.

Obviously this isn't as easy as just adjusting X, as when it moves round to the side of the star I'll have to adjust Y as well. I'm wondering how I could use some math to figure out how much I need to adjust X and Y by as the object moves around the star.

Here's my code so far:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

var star = {
    x: c.width / 2,
    y: c.height / 2,
    r: 100,
    g: 2,
    draw: function()
    {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
};

var node = {
    x: c.width / 2,
    y: 100,
    r: 20,
    draw: function()
    {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
};


//GAME LOOP
function gameLoop()
{
    update();
    render();
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

function update()
{
    //Move towards star
    var dx = star.x - node.x;
    var dy = star.y - node.y;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    
    node.x += Math.cos(angle);
    node.y += Math.sin(angle);
    
    //Lateral movement
    node.x += 2;
}

function render()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    star.draw();
    node.draw();
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        body
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        #canvas
        {
            background-color: #001319;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas">
        </canvas>
        <script src="Orbit.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Are you drawing a circle, with the sun in the middle, or 2) an ellipse with the sun in 1 focus point, ... and 3) does the orbit process (the ellipse itself rotates around a point...)?

Answer (score 5):

### Newton's and Kepler's clockwork universe

When Newton worked out the maths for calculating orbits he noted something that prompted him to coin the term "clockwork universe". In a two body simulation the orbital paths of both objects repeat precisely. This mean that both objects will at the same time be in the exact same position at the exact same speed they were in the last orbit, there will be no precession.

#### Gravity, force, mass, and distance.

For a more accurate model of gravity you can use the laws of gravity as discovered by Newton. **F = G * (m1*m2)/(r*r)** where **F** is force, **G** is the Gravitational constant (and for simulations it is just a scaling factor) **m1**,**m2** are the mass of each body and **r** is the distance between the bodies.

#### Mass of a sphere

We give both the star and planet some mass. Let's say that in the computer 1 pixel cubed is equal to 1 unit mass. Thus the mass of a sphere of radius **R** is **4/3 * R<sup>3</sup> * PI**.

#### Force, mass, and acceleration

The force is always applied along the line between the bodies and is called acceleration.

When a force is applied to an object we use another of Newton's discovered laws, **F=ma** where **a** is acceleration. We have the **F** (force) and **m** (mass) so now all we need is **a**. Rearrange **F=ma** to get **a = f/m**.

If we look at both formulas in terms of **a** (acceleration) **a =  (G * (m1*m2)/(r*r)) / m1** we can see that the mass of the object we are apply force to is cancelled out **a = G * (m2)/(r*r)**. Now we can calculate the acceleration due to gravity. Acceleration is just change in velocity over time, and we know that that change is in the direction of the other body. So we get the vector between the bodies (`o1`,`o2` for object 1 and 2) `dx = o2.x-o1.x`, `dy = o2.y-o1.y` Then find the length of that vector (which is the **r** in the gravity formula) `dist =  Math.sqrt(dx* dx + dy * dy)`. Then we normalise the vector (make its length = one) by dividing by its length. `dx /= dist`, `dy /= dist`. Calculate the a (acceleration) and multiply the normalised vector between the object by **a** then add that to the object's velocity and that is it. Perfect Newtonian clockwork orbits (for two bodies that is).

#### Clean up with Kepler.

All that math is good but it does not make for a nice simulation. When the math is done both objects start moving and if the starting velocities are not in balance then the whole system will slowly drift of the canvas.

We could just make the display relative to one of the bodies, this would eliminate any drift in the system, but we still have the problem of getting an orbit. If one object is moving to fast it will fly off and never come back. If it is going too slow then it will fall in very close to the centerpoint of the other object. If this happens the change in velocity will approch infinity, something computers are not that good at handling.

So to get nice circular orbits we need one last bit of math.

Using Kepler's second law modified to fit into Newton's math we get a formula that will give the approximate (It is an approximate as the actual calculations involve an infinite series and I can not be bothered writing that out.) orbital velocity **v = sqrt(G*(m1 + m2)/r)**. It looks similar to Newton's gravity law but in this the masses are summed not multiplied, and the distance is not squared.

So we use this to calculate the tangential speed of both bodies to give them near circular orbits. It is important that each object go in the opposite direction to each other.

I created a setup function that sets up the correct orbits for both the sun and the planet. But the value of **G** (Gravitational constant) is likely way to large. To get a better value I scale **G** (via kludge math) so that the sun's orbit speed is close to a desired ideal `sunV` (pixels per frame) To make the whole sim run quicker increase this value

As I have set up the code to have more than two bodies the calculation of starting velocity will only work if each object is significantly more massive than the next. I have added a moon (you need to un-comment to see) to the planet, but it is too big and it's starting velocity is a little too low. It gets pulled (gravity sling shot) by the Earth into a higher orbit,. but this also pulls the earth into a lower orbit making its orbit more eccentric

> **NOTE** After all that I find that something is not quite right and there is still a tiny bit of drift in the system. As I am out of time I have just fixed the sun position to keep the system on the canvas.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
c.width = innerWidth;
c.height = innerHeight;
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
const STAR_RADIUS = 100;
const PLANET_RADIUS = 10;
const MOON_RADIUS = 4.5;
var G = 1; // gravitational constant is not so constant as need to 
           // scale it to find best value for the system. 
           // for that I will scale it so that the suns orbital speed around the 
           // planet is approx 0.1 pixels per frame
const sunV = 0.1; // the sun's orbital desired speed. THis is used to tune G               
const DRAW = function () {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.col;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
var star = {
    x: c.width / 2,
    y: c.height / 2,
    vx : 0,
    vy : 0,
    r: STAR_RADIUS,
    mass : (4/3) * Math.pow(STAR_RADIUS,3) * Math.PI,
    col : 'orange',
    draw : DRAW,
};
// kludge to fix drift
const sunStartX = star.x;
const sunStartY = star.y;

var node = {
    x: c.width / 2 - STAR_RADIUS - PLANET_RADIUS * 5,
    y: c.height / 2,
    r: PLANET_RADIUS,
    mass : (4/3) * Math.pow(PLANET_RADIUS,3) * Math.PI,
    col : "blue",
    draw : DRAW,
    vx: -1,
    vy: 0,
};

var moon = {
    x: c.width / 2- STAR_RADIUS - PLANET_RADIUS * 7 ,
    y: c.height / 2,
    r: MOON_RADIUS,
    mass : (4/3) * Math.pow(PLANET_RADIUS,3) * Math.PI,
    col : "#888",
    draw : DRAW,
    vx: -1,
    vy: 0,
};
const objects = [star, node];//, moon];
function setup(){
    var dist,dx,dy,o1,o2,v,c,dv;
    o1 = objects[0];
    o1.vx = 0;
    o1.vy = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < objects.length; j ++){
        if(j !== 0){ // object can not apply force to them selves
            o2 = objects[j];
            dx = o2.x - o1.x;
            dy = o2.y - o1.y;
            dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            dx /= dist;  
            dy /= dist;
            // Find value og G
            if(j === 1){ // is this not  sun
                v = Math.sqrt(G  * ( o2.mass ) / dist);
                dv = sunV - v;
                while(Math.abs(dv) > sunV * sunV){
                    if(dv < 0){  // sun too fast
                        G *= 0.75;
                    }else{
                        G += G * 0.1;
                    }
                    v = Math.sqrt(G  * ( o2.mass ) / dist);
                    dv = sunV - v;
                }
            }
            
            v = Math.sqrt(G  * ( o2.mass ) / dist);
            o1.vx -= v * dy; // along the tangent
            o1.vy += v * dx;
        }
    }
    for(var i = 1; i < objects.length; i ++){
        o1 = objects[i];
        o1.vx = 0;
        o1.vy = 0;
        for(var j = 0; j <objects.length; j ++){
            if(j !== i){
                o2 = objects[j];
                dx = o2.x - o1.x;
                dy = o2.y - o1.y;
                dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                dx /= dist;  
                dy /= dist;                    
                v = Math.sqrt(G  * ( o2.mass ) / dist);
                o1.vx += v * dy; // along the tangent
                o1.vy -= v * dx;
            }
        }
    }
}


//GAME LOOP
function gameLoop(){
    update();
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

// every object exerts a force on every other object
function update(){
    var dist,dx,dy,o1,o2,a;
    // find force of acceleration each object applies to each object
    for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++){
        o1 = objects[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < objects.length; j ++){
            if(i !== j){ // object can not apply force to them selves
                o2 = objects[j];
                dx = o2.x - o1.x;
                dy = o2.y - o1.y;
                dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                dx /= dist;  // normalise the line between the objects (makes the vector 1 unit long)
                dy /= dist;
                // get force
                a = (G  * o2.mass ) / (dist * dist);
                o1.vx += a * dx;
                o1.vy += a * dy;
            }
        }
    }
    // once all the forces have been found update objects positions
    for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++){
        o1 = objects[i];
        o1.x += o1.vx;
        o1.y += o1.vy;
    }
            
}

function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  // kludge to fix drift
    var offsetX =  objects[0].x - sunStartX;
    var offsetY =  objects[0].y - sunStartY;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,-offsetX,-offsetY);

    for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++){
        objects[i].draw();
    }
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
setup();
requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've answered my own question.

Rather than making the star's gravity directly affect the x and y coordinates, I have a vx and vy of the object, and I cause the gravity to affect that value, and then just adjust x and y by vx and vy on each update.

Here's the code:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

var star = {
    x: c.width / 2,
    y: c.height / 2,
    r: 100,
    g: 0.5,
    draw: function()
    {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
};

var node = {
    x: c.width / 2,
    y: 50,
    r: 20,
    vx: 15,
    vy: 0,
    draw: function()
    {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
};


//GAME LOOP
function gameLoop()
{
    update();
    render();
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

function update()
{
    node.x += node.vx;
    node.y += node.vy;
    
    //Move towards star
    var dx = star.x - node.x;
    var dy = star.y - node.y;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    
    node.vx += (Math.cos(angle) * star.g);
    node.vy += (Math.sin(angle) * star.g);
}

function render()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    star.draw();
    node.draw();
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: That's an interesting orbit you've got going on there. I added the `<canvas>` element to your snippet, since it crashed without it. In the event you don't already know, you can use the `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` functions to calculate the orbit in a more natural (circular) manner. One calculates the x position, the other the y position. The input is the angle, which ranges from [0..2pi] (radians) rather than the more widely known [0..360] (degrees)